# Improving the relevance of production errors reporting

Tags: c#, exception, logging, model-view-controller, relevance

The support mailbox became unusable :

In our mvc application, we catch exceptions thrown at several places (OnException implemented, try/catch in InvokeActionMethod, etc.) and we send a mail for each place (with a log4net appender). This results in an abundance of error mails in the common exchange mailbox which become unusable efficiently (we took a week and 1000+ mails to see that an additional site wouldn't communicate anymore with our main application) : Too much information kills the information.

However, each mail coming from another place, we sometimes get different and relevant informations from differents contexts.

My questions are : did you experience the same issue ? how did you solved it without loosing crucial informations / without missing an important crash ?

*Here are some of my thoughts : 
- Having a way to see that an exception already initiated an email, but this might results in the missing of some additionnal relevant information
- Creating an Outlook plugin to try to group mulitples emails coming from a unique exception, but that would negate the benefits of common exchange mailbox
- Finding a better tool than Outlook to organize error emails*

Comment: Welcome to the site! As it stands, this question isn't a good fit for the site ethos; StackOverflow prefers questions that can be answered, rather than discussed. I would expect that it will attract downvotes and close votes but please don't let that put you off - it's just that this isn't a narrow and specific problem to which there is a clear cut factual answer

Comment: As a side comment we file our error reports in an azure blob table and summarize them by type, graphing them by count. You probably need to devise a storage mechanism for yours that allows summary, drill down and trend analysis; email by email inspection doesn't cut it